# Does glMapBuffer occupy GPU time?

Tags: opengl, pbo

A common usage of glMapBuffer is

```
previousPBO.render();
bindNextPBO();
GLubyte* src = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
if(src) {
    doSomeWork(src);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
}
```

There are 2 PBO working in alternative way.

However, sometimes, the doSomeWork(.) may be in another thread. If the code above applied, 
current thread must wait for doSomeWork() to finish. Another solution is:

```
previousPBO.render();
bindNextPBO();
if(currentPBO.mapped) {
    currentPBO.mapped = false;
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
}
GLubyte* src = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
if(src) {
    currentPBO.mapped = true;
    doSomeWork(src);
}
```

In this case, the map->unmap procedure of the same PBO spans two frames.

- Does the unmapped state of PBO stall the rendering of GPU?
- Any bad influence on performance?

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet is just WRONG.  What if `doSomeWork` didn't finish in time?  Now it is accessing memory that you unmapped, and will cause an access violation (or worse).

A better approach is to wait for completion of the other thread and unmap the buffer at the end of the frame just before `SwapBuffers`.

Comment: This situation can be easily avoided by global state. When current thread reaches glUnmapBuffer(), if doSomeWork() not finish yet, only a much smaller waiting time is needed. If there are no other disadvantages, it will abtain some benifit of asynchronization.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, that's why I recommended processing the remainder of the frame and waiting for the other task only at the end of the frame.

Comment: It's not always convenient to arrange other works at the end of frame. So, what is the difference between unmap at begin and at end?

Comment: @Martin: It's not the unmap, it's the waiting for the other threads to finish before ending the frame.

Comment: If other works done before unmap, e.g. processing another PBO, does mapped PBO affect GPU's performance?